The requested module '@stencil/core/internal/client/index.js' does not provide an export named 'getAssetPath'
In a NUXT/VUE evironment, using @arcgis/core@4.29.10, importing anything else but Map causes this error:

The requested module '@stencil/core/internal/client/index.js' does not
provide an export named 'getAssetPath'
at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:189:5)

I've searched and found some posts, but nothing that involves NUXT/VUE for this problem.
Global:
├── corepack@0.17.1
├── npm@9.6.3
└── vue@3.4.27
local:
├── @arcgis/core@4.29.10
├── nuxt@3.11.2
└── vue-router@4.3.2

